# Why mutating cell array in a class property is so slow?

Tags: performance, matlab

For example, I have the following class:

```
classdef testclass < handle
    properties
            buckets
    end
    methods
        function tc = testclass(sz)
            tc.buckets = cell(1, sz);
        end
        function put(tc,k)
            tc.buckets{k}{1} = 1;
        end
    end
end
```

And the following example loop, where I compare performance with a plain cell array:

```
tm = @java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis;

for N=[100 200 400 1000 2000 4000 8000]
    tc = testclass(N);
    Tstart = tm();
    for k=1:N
        tc.put(k);
    end
    Tend = tm();
    fprintf(1, 'filling hash class (size %d): %d ms\n', N, Tend - Tstart);

    arr = cell(1,N);
    Tstart = tm();
    for k=1:N
        arr{k}{1} = 1;
    end
    Tend = tm();
    fprintf(1, 'filling cell array (size %d): %d ms\n', N, Tend - Tstart);
end
```

The output is:

```
filling hash class (size 100): 8 ms
filling cell array (size 100): 0 ms
filling hash class (size 200): 9 ms
filling cell array (size 200): 0 ms
filling hash class (size 400): 24 ms
filling cell array (size 400): 1 ms
filling hash class (size 1000): 108 ms
filling cell array (size 1000): 2 ms
filling hash class (size 2000): 370 ms
filling cell array (size 2000): 5 ms
filling hash class (size 4000): 1396 ms
filling cell array (size 4000): 10 ms
filling hash class (size 8000): 5961 ms
filling cell array (size 8000): 21 ms
```

As you can see, plain cell array exhibits "linear" performance (which is to be expected), but array wrapped in a class gives horrible quadratic performance.

I tested this on Matlab 2008a and Matlab 2010a.

What causes this? And how can I work around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The true power of Matlab is only available to those who know what to avoid :)

One major issue with OOP in interpreted languages (Matlab is not alone in this) is the rather spectacular overhead involved with calling methods, as you have noticed. OOP requires completely different design strategies in Matlab, Python, etc. than in C++, Fortran, etc.

Anyway, you had best avoid calling methods so often, and vectorize as much as you can.

Compare this:

```
clc, clear classes    
feature accel off  % to make sure JIT doesn't throw things off

tm = @java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis;

for N = [100 200 400 1000 2000 4000 8000]

    tc = testclass(N);

    % call method inside loop
    Tstart = tm();
    for k=1:N
        tc.put(k);
    end
    Tend = tm();
    fprintf(1, 'filling hash class (loop, size %d)      : %d ms\n', N, Tend - Tstart);

    % call method only once
    Tstart = tm();
    tc.put(1:N);    
    Tend = tm();
    fprintf(1, 'filling hash class (vectorized, size %d): %d ms\n', N, Tend - Tstart);

    % cell-array direct assignment, looped version
    arr = cell(1,N);
    Tstart = tm();
    for k=1:N
        arr{k}{1} = 1;
    end
    Tend = tm();
    fprintf(1, 'filling cell array (loop, size %d)      : %d ms\n', N, Tend - Tstart);

    % cell-array direct assignment, vectorized version
    arr = cell(1,N);
    Tstart = tm();
    [arr{:}] = deal({1});
    Tend = tm();
    fprintf(1, 'filling cell array (vectorized, size %d): %d ms\n\n', N, Tend - Tstart);
end
```

where the relevant method in `testclass` is modified to handle vectorized as well as looped assignments:

```
classdef testclass < handle
    properties
            buckets
    end
    methods
        function tc = testclass(sz)
            tc.buckets = cell(1, sz);
        end
        function put(tc,k)
            [tc.buckets{k}] = deal({1});
        end
    end
end
```

Results:

```
filling hash class (loop, size 100)      : 5 ms
filling hash class (vectorized, size 100): 0 ms
filling cell array (loop, size 100)      : 0 ms
filling cell array (vectorized, size 100): 0 ms

filling hash class (loop, size 200)      : 7 ms
filling hash class (vectorized, size 200): 0 ms
filling cell array (loop, size 200)      : 0 ms
filling cell array (vectorized, size 200): 0 ms

filling hash class (loop, size 400)      : 15 ms
filling hash class (vectorized, size 400): 1 ms
filling cell array (loop, size 400)      : 1 ms
filling cell array (vectorized, size 400): 0 ms

filling hash class (loop, size 1000)      : 36 ms
filling hash class (vectorized, size 1000): 2 ms
filling cell array (loop, size 1000)      : 2 ms
filling cell array (vectorized, size 1000): 1 ms

filling hash class (loop, size 2000)      : 73 ms
filling hash class (vectorized, size 2000): 2 ms
filling cell array (loop, size 2000)      : 4 ms
filling cell array (vectorized, size 2000): 2 ms

filling hash class (loop, size 4000)      : 145 ms
filling hash class (vectorized, size 4000): 5 ms
filling cell array (loop, size 4000)      : 9 ms
filling cell array (vectorized, size 4000): 4 ms

filling hash class (loop, size 8000)      : 292 ms
filling hash class (vectorized, size 8000): 8 ms
filling cell array (loop, size 8000)      : 18 ms
filling cell array (vectorized, size 8000): 9 ms
```

Comment: I understand that calling methods imposes overhead (I actually fell into classic "t-test in a loop" pitfall recently, vectorization really helped things there). What I don't understand is why this overhead is quadratic - even the aforementioned python doesn't have it. What could cause that quadratic behavior?

Comment: Also, in the specific case I'm trying to optimize, I'm not able to vectorize code - because what I'm implementing is basically a HashMap, so I have to call `put` method a lot of times (2008a doesn't have `containers.Map` yet, and `java.util.HashMap` doesn't work in that case, either).

Comment: @Rogach: There's nearly always a way to vectorize, problem is, it might be very not-obvious and esotheric compared to a looped solution. My test shows that Matlab R2012a at least seems to have linear performance -- compare `N=1000` (36ms) vs `N=8000` (292ms ≈ 8*36ms)

Comment: Yes, seems that in 2012a that problem went away. Sadly, I can't use 2012a at my workplace, so it seems that I am stuck :(

Comment: @Rogach: If you are willing to share more code, I can help you vectorize it...There's probably a way.

Comment: @Rogach: You have my e-mail, I think that's best.

Comment: I think that if I would abandon the idea of hash maps, I would be able to easily vectorize it myself - the whole idea was to use hash map to memorize a lot of data (16 subjects, 150 locations, 6 time intervals, 6 situations), accessed by keys describing each data point. It turns out that my naive hash map works, but inserting all those data points into the map takes about 20 minutes each run (about 25% of the total time). So it's acceptable, I was just seeking a way to make it better.

Comment: But I think that I will either leave the current solution intact, or use something like trees for lookups instead.

Answer (score 0):

> What causes this? And how can I work around it?

The slowdown is the result of using Objects.  Objects buy you a lot as programmer, however, they involve overhead.  You cannot get around this overhead without abandoning objects. Depending on the language and your particular implementation the overhead will be trivial or substantial.

I wrote a simple C++ program that creates an object with a member array and a naked array. Filling the array inside the object takes much longer than filling the naked array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
 
static const int MAX_SIZE  = 1000000;
 
class Holder{
  public:
    void putValue(int val, int idx);
  private:
        int data[MAX_SIZE];
};
 
void Holder::putValue(int v, int i){
        data[i] = v;
}
 
int main(int argc, char **argv){
 
        Holder h;
        int data[MAX_SIZE];
 
        
        int j, i;
        clock_t begin, end;
        int outerLoop = 200;
 
        fprintf(stderr,"Testing array in object!\n");
        begin = clock();
        for ( j=0; j<outerLoop; j++)
                for (  i = 0; i<MAX_SIZE; i++)
                        h.putValue(i,i);
        end = clock();
 
        fprintf(stderr,"Done! El time:%3.3f\n", double(end - begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
 
 
        fprintf(stderr,"Testing naked array 2!\n");
        begin = clock();
        for ( j=0; j<outerLoop; j++)
                for ( i = 0; i<MAX_SIZE; i++)
                        data[i] = i;
        end = clock();
        fprintf(stderr,"Done! El time:%3.3f\n", double(end - begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
 
 
}
```

Here is the output:

> Testing array in object!
>
> Done! El time:1.413
>
> Testing naked array 2!
>
> Done! El time:0.690

Comment: What you use to compile that? I tried gcc, it fails with `Holder.cc:27: error: ‘stderr’ was not declared in this scope`.

Comment: While I'm unable to compile that (mostly because I never used C++ before), I must note that I completely understand that function calls impose overhead. But it the overhead is linear, and overhead of calling the function in C is surely not dependent of member variables! I suspect that if you would increase MAX_SIZE (for example, to 10000000), you'll still see linear increase in used time - 14s and 6s, respectively. Not quadratic, which I experience in my example.

Comment: @Rogach, have you read this? http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2012/03/26/considering-performance-in-object-oriented-matlab-code/  I haven't read the whole thing but it looks like Loren does discuss benchmarking and performance of objects

Comment: Haven't read that yet, thanks for the link! Will read it now.

Comment: Well, that link talks about linear optimizations - there's not a single word about such horrible performances on such small arrays.

Comment: I also managed to compile your example, and got the results as expected - using array inside an object is always about 2x slower, but decreasing the amount of cycles doesn't change the speed dramatically. By the way, increasing `MAX_SIZE` gives me a segfault - why?

Comment: @Rogach probably because MAX_SIZE was overflowing the storage capacity of an `int`

Comment: @Rogach, You'll need to change the indexing variables `i` and `j` to long ints as well.  If that doesn't fix it then i'm not sure what the problem is

Comment: I did that change, the problem still is there. Quick google states that stack size could be an issue, and my nonexistent knowledge of C makes me unable to fix that. Regardless, that example doesn't prove the point - the object wrapper doesn't impose quadratic penalty.